Razor Pages routing with @page
The Razor Pages routing using the @page directive seems to rewrite the links.
I've created a "ASP.NET Core Web App (Razor Pages)" application using the template:
 dotnet new razor -f net8.0

Updating the @page directive in the Index.cshtml page to @page "{id:int?}" allows for routing to /index and /index/1, for example. Unfortunately the link to the Home page, the index page, will show up with the identity after it's first used.
For example, update the URL to ~/index/1 and visit the page. The page shows up fine. The link to the home page, however, now shows as ~/1 on hover (for instance, https://localhost:7249/1).
This obviously doesn't matter in this example but it's affecting a real application I'm developing where the page without an identifier in the main menu is being overwritten by the link to page with the last identifier used so the user can't navigate to the default page.
Have I done something wrong? Is there some configuration of the routing that isn't in the default configuration in Program.cs? I expected the routing to work "out of the box".

The link behavior you're experiencing is by design. Microsoft's documentation refers to it as ambient values.

From the current request, routing accesses the route values of the current request HttpContext.Request.RouteValues. The values associated with the current request are referred to as the ambient values.

The documentation after the above definition, however, is not very helpful. A resource that provides a better explanation is provided in The Anchor Tag Helper page on learnrazorpages.com.

Route Data values for the current request are considered ambient values... This means that they do not necessarily need to be specified when generating links [to the current page].

The Anchor Tag Helper will generate a link to the index/home page, as in your example, using the route data values (i.e. the value of the optional id route data value).
<a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>

results in:
<a href="/1">Home</a>

To override this behavior, you need to explicitly set the value for the asp-route-id route data parameter, as referenced in the learnrazorpages.com link above:

In this case, you only need to specify a value for asp-route-* if you want to override the ambient value.

In your case, you do not want any route data value to appear in the anchor tag generated by the anchor Tag Helper. Set asp-route-id to an empty string.
<a asp-page="/Index" asp-route-id="">Home</a>

The result:
<a href="/">Home</a>

Additional references
There are references to the change in ASP.NET Core behavior regarding the use of ambient values. This is only for Anchor Tag Helper elements that are not referencing the current page. This SO post asks to preserve ambient values in anchor elements that are to links to different resources from the current page and provides a solution on how to do that.

The addition of the empty asp-route-id works for the links in the page. Thank you. The links in the _Layout.cshtml, however, change whether the empty id is set or not! I can't find a way to stop the nav bar links from changing.

I could not find a way to clear the route data value in an Anchor Tag Helper in _Layout.cshtml to an empty value. The Anchor Tag Helper will accept a valid int as an override in _Layout.cshtml. Unlike an empty value in the Razor Page view, the Anchor Tag Helper generates inconsistent/unexpected output in _Layout.cshtml. I searched for a bug reported for this inconsistency, but have yet to find a post for it.

The only workaround is to forgo the use of the Anchor Tag Helper in _Layout.cshtml and explicitly set the a tag. When you set the href attribute and remove the Tag Helper attributes (i.e. asp-page), the ambient data value is not added to the href attribute.

Thank you, @dave-b, hardcoding the URL in the _Layout.cshtml works for me.

If you want to make the url /index/1 instead of /1. Configure the @page directive like below:
@page "/index/{id:int?}"
@model IndexModel
<a asp-page="index">test</a>

By default, the routing of Index.cshtml is / when application first running. If you want to maintain this behavior, be sure add the following configuration in Program.cs:
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/", "/Index");

The change url is expected behavior when you use asp-page or @Url.Page.
If you want to make the url unchanged, you need hard coded the url instead of using tag helper or @Url.Page:
<a href="/index">test</a>


I've tested this and it doesn't change the behaviour described in the question. The links are being rewritten to, for example, "http://localhost:5083/index/1". The actual links are rewritten to "http://localhost:5083/index/1". Navigate to another page, i.e. 'Privacy', and then the links are reset to the expected defaults, i.e. '~/index'.

Of course. Only if you write the absolute url, otherwise it will always change by your request url dynamically. So you want the url  always generate without identity?

Adding another link to the page shows the effect well. In addition to the link you suggested, "test", I added, "test 0". Clicking between these links clearly shows the rewritting behaviour. Is this expected?

Also tried, "test 0".

Hi @Boggin, actually it is be design. Cause the tag helper will dynamically generate the url with optional value by your current request url. So again, is your requirement to achieve keep the url  unchanged no matter the request url contains identity or not?

Thanks, @Rena, I suspected I was using it incorrectly. Yes, I'm wanting the URL to be unchanged. How should I do that?

Hi @Boggin, actually this is the expected behavior and what you did is correct if you use no matter asp-page or @Url.Page . If you always want the url unchanged, you need hard coded by using <a href="/index">test</a>

Thank you, @Rena, hardcoding the URL in the _Layout.cshtml works for me.
